# Unable to create new compute instances in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a new GPU instance in GCP but I keep getting the following error:

*A n1-standard-1 VM instance is currently unavailable in the us-central1-a zone. Alternatively, you can try your request again with a different VM hardware configuration or at a later time. For more information, see the troubleshooting documentation.*

I understand GPU machines are limited, so I tried different regions and zones and I keep getting the same error. I also tried creating a normal machine and got the same error. Checked my billing settings and couldn't see anything out of place.

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Comment: For those reading this in the future. Smaller machine types such as `n1-standard-1` are in high demand in some regions. This error message means that resource type is not available at that instant in time. The message informs the user of the options: a) wait; b) select a different instance size or configuration; c) select a different region. When I see this error, I select a larger instance size. Later (about a week), I resize it back to the size I need long term.

Answer (score 0):

use this command for check what type of vm  is available :
$ gcloud compute machine-types list --filter="us-central1-a"

then you can see list of type vm that are available in us-central1-a and you can change type of your vm to this (:

Comment: Your answer shows the list of VM types that can be created but there might not be inventory (compute resources) available at the point in time to create or launch one.

Comment: yes but often after execute this command you can find your resource easily

Comment: Your answer does not apply to the question asked. I am not downvoting your answer so that you can learn the difference. Please update your answer with a correct solution.